# ensureCleanSession: true doesn't seem to work even though placed in capabilities for IE 11

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am testing a **login/logout** application using **protractor**.

I have a popup that appears after login and this has to happen for each login/logout scenario.

To make the popup to appear after each login, I have to clean the `IE` browser session after each restart of `IE` browser.

I have tried with        `browser.driver.manage().deleteCookie();` and `browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();` but unable to clean session in `IE` browser.

Please suggest to me a workaround that can clean session after each block or any.
Thanks in advance,
A Happy Tester.:-)

Answer (score 0):

At last it worked for me

```
browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
```

Thanks for all.